Multivariate quotient rule for partial derivatives of dot product between normalized (unit) vector and another vector with respect to first vector
I would like to confirm that the following is a correct application of a multivariate quotient rule as explained in the answer to Quotient rule extendable to functions of vectors?
For any vectors $x=[x_1\ \cdots\ x_N]$, $y=[y_1\ \cdots\ y_N]\in\mathbb{R}^N$ and norm $\|x\|=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i^2\ }$, we have the partial derivatives
$$\frac{∂}{∂x_i}\left[\frac{x}{‖x‖}\cdot y\right]= \frac{y_i}{‖x‖} - \left(\frac{x}{‖x‖}\cdot y\right)\frac{x_i}{‖x‖^2}\qquad\forall i=1,\dots,N\quad .$$
Assumptions:

As explained in the linked answer, for $f,g,h:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}$ with $h(x):=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, at some point $x$ where $f,g$ are differentiable and $g(x)\neq0$, we have
$$
\frac{∂}{∂x_i}\left[\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right]=\left(\frac{1}{g(x)^2}\right)\left(\frac{∂f(x)}{∂x_i}g(x)\ -\ f(x)\frac{∂g(x)}{∂x_i}\right)
$$



$$\frac{∂f(x)}{∂x_i}\ =\ \frac{∂}{∂x_i}\left[x\cdot h\right]\ =\ h_i\qquad\qquad\forall i=1,\dots,N\quad
$$
3)
$$\frac{∂g(x)}{∂x_i}\ =\ \frac{∂}{∂x_i}‖x‖\ =\ \frac{x_i}{‖x‖}\qquad\qquad\forall i=1,\dots,N\quad
$$
$\ $
Therefore, putting the assumptions together (if they're correct) at any $x\neq0$ gives:
$$
\frac{∂}{∂x_i}\left[\frac{x}{‖x‖}\cdot y\right]= \left(\frac{1}{‖x‖^2}\right)\left(y_i\,‖x‖\ -\ (x\cdot y)\frac{x_i}{‖x‖}\right)\qquad\qquad\forall i=1,\dots,N
$$
and distributing the $\frac{1}{‖x‖^2}$ then gives the same expression as the claim at the start of the question.
Does this seem reasonably correct?

You are writing the quotient rule in an unusual way. Sometimes is best to write it out in full: $\partial_{x_i} (\sum_k x_k y_k) / \sqrt{\sum_k x_k^2} = (y_i \sqrt{\sum_k x_k^2} - (\sum_k x_ky_k) x_i/ \sqrt{\sum_k x_k^2})/\sum_k x_k^2 = (y_i |x| - x^\intercal y x_i/|x|)/|x|^2=y_i/|x|-x^\intercal y x_i/|x|^3.$
